# Is quick.db supported on Glitch?

Tags: javascript, database, quick.db

Is possible to use the Database "quick.db" on Glitch?
I tried to use in Visual Studio Code and worked fine, but when i tried on Glitch, didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use quick.db on Glitch, on their website they only show information on how to install in Linux, Windows and Mac. They don't show how to install in a specific platform.
You can look at their website:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db

https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db

You can ask the development team in their discord server:

https://discord.gg/plexiev